# Для чего нужен метод BigInteger probablyPrime ?

Tags: java, biginteger

Наткнулся на метод probablePrime в классе BigInteger, кто-то может объяснить для чего он нужен, и как он работает ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Он используется в криптографии. В [алгоритме шифрования RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) производится поиск огромных простых чисел, зачастую больше 1024 бит или ~300 знаков.
Надёжность RSA состоит в том на том, что разложить на множители два таких числа, умноженые друг на друга невероятно тяжело и долго.

Метод `BigInteger.probablePrime(...)` генерирует случайное число и использует [Тест Миллера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) для определения простое оно или нет, в результате у числа вероятность быть составным не превышает `2^-100`.